# fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'root@pegasusv.(none)')?

Tags: git, github

```
pegasus@pegasusv:/linux_work/linux_stable$ sudo git commit -a
[sudo] password for pegasus: 
Author identity unknown

*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'root@pegasusv.(none)')
```

How can I fix the error?

Here's my global .gitconfig file:

```
#[safe]
#       directory = /linux_work/linux
#       directory = /linux_work/linux-kselftest
[user]
        name = Zeshan Ahmed Nobin
        email = zeshanahmednobin@gmail.com

[format]
        signoff = true
[core]
        editor = vim

[sendmail]
        smtpserver = mail.xxxx.com
        smtpserverport = portnum
        smtpencryption = tls
        smtpuser = user
        smtppass = password


[safe]
        directory = /linux_work/linux_stable
```

Trying to push to this repo:
`git remote add linux git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git`

The local .git directory:

```
 Netrw Directory Listing                                        (netrw v171)
"   /linux_work/linux_stable/.git
"   Sorted by      name
"   Sort sequence: [\/]$,\<core\%(\.\d\+\)\=\>,\.h$,\.c$,\.cpp$,\~\=\*$,*,\.o$,\.obj$,\.info$,\.swp$,\.bak$,\~$
"   Quick Help: <F1>:help  -:go up dir  D:delete  R:rename  s:sort-by  x:special
" ==============================================================================
../
./
branches/
hooks/
info/
logs/
objects/
refs/
FETCH_HEAD
HEAD
config
description
index
packed-refs
```

Comment: the error says exactly how you can fix it (I suspect a subtle syntax error). Also, your local configuration might be overloading your global one. And the fact that you're getting something involving `root@` probably means you somehow created git files using root and now can't change them.

Comment: also, unless you're Linus Torvalds, you won't be able to push to that repo :D :D :D

Comment: Here's the .gitconifg file permissions

`-rw-rw-r--  1 pegasus pegasus  372 এপ্রিল    25 03:34 .gitconfig`

Comment: There's a local git which is set to root
but should I delete it?

Comment: that's most definitely broken; `.git` should be a directory.

Comment: Yeah .git is a directory. My bad

Comment: When using sudo (without specifying a user), you're working as root. Which means, the configuration of the user `root` is relevant. Not the configuration of the user `pegasus`.  If it is a good idea to use root to work with git is another discussion.

Comment: Not really, in this use case it's unambiguously bad and now op has a .git directory that doesn't even belong to their user...